# Rails Hash complex group with two min, max

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, group-by

I am trying to analyze the structure below trying to get a result grouped by Soccer Player, showing for each player the first two best events and the first two worse events. Last element should be the difference (in percentage) between 1st best and 1st worse and 2nd best and 2nd worse.

This is the structure:

```
[{"id"=>1,
  "event"=>"Brazil-Croatia",
  "player"=>"Neymar",
  "goals"=>2,
  "assists"=>10.3,
  "pass_success_pct"=>32.10,
 {"id"=>2,
  "event"=>"Austria-Brazil",
  "player"=>"Neymar",
  "goals"=>0,
  "assists"=>3,
  "pass_success_pct"=>45.23,
 {"id"=>3,
  "event"=>"Barcelona-Real Madrid",
  "player"=>Lionel Messi",
  "goals"=>1,
  "assists"=>4,
  "pass_success_pct"=>98.2,
......
 {"id"=>400,
  "event"=>"Argentina-Croatia",
  "player"=>"Lionel Messi",
  "goals"=>2,
  "assists"=>12,
  "pass_success_pct"=>99.12}
]
```

The result should be:

```
[{"player"=>"Neymar", "event"=>"Brazil-Costa Rica", "position"=>'1st Best', "goals"=>3, "difference_pct"=>11.34},
{"player"=>"Neymar", "event"=>"Paris Saint Germain-Strasbourg", "position"=>'2nd Best', "goals"=>2, "difference_pct"=>8.12},
{"player"=>"Neymar", "event"=>"Brazil-Switzerland", "position"=>'1st Worse', "goals"=>1, "difference_pct"=>4.2},
{"player"=>"Neymar", "event"=>"Toulouse-Paris Saint Germain", "position"=>'2nd Worse', "goals"=>0, "difference_pct"=>2.10}
]
```

I'm a big fan of SQL queries, but this is a big challenge to me
Thank you
Max

Comment: And what did you try? What the problem did you meet?

Comment: I tried this approach:

    table.group_by do |h|
      h.values_at("player") 
    end.map do |_, v| 
      v.max_by { |h| h["goals"] },
      v.min_by { |h| h["goals"] }

But I'am getting TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer, and also I believe .map is suitable for single operation, isn't it?
end